# Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vite, polyfills

i converted my create react app to vite and after that i got many errors

- first one is `process is not defined` so i add this line to vite config file

  ```
   define: {
    'process.env': {},
  },
  ```

and this solved the problem and then

- i got another error which said
  `Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string`
  and the stack of this error returned to library call `graceful-fs`

  ```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string
    at Object.get (browser-external:fs:9:102)
    at node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js (graceful-fs.js:43:6)
    at __require2 (chunk-TFWDKVI3.js?v=df258961:18:50)
    at node_modules/decompress/index.js (index.js:3:12)
    at __require2 (chunk-TFWDKVI3.js?v=df258961:18:50)
    at node_modules/download/index.js (index.js:7:20)
    at __require2 (chunk-TFWDKVI3.js?v=df258961:18:50)
    at index.js:99:1
  ```

and right now i'm stuck , everytime i run the app it gives me an empty page with this error logged in the console

i think the problem with `fs module` because when i clicked on `browser-external:fs:9:102` in the error stack, the file was look like this

```
module.exports = Object.create(new Proxy({}, {
get(_, key) {
if (
  key !== '__esModule' &&
  key !== '__proto__' &&
  key !== 'constructor' &&
  key !== 'splice'
) {
  console.warn(`Module "fs" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "fs.${key}" in client code. See http://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#module-externalized-for-browser-compatibility for more details.`) } } }))
```

and according the vite documentation, i added `patch package` to solve this by installing it and add it to npm scripts

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
   }
```

**but still give me an empty page with this error logged in the console**

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with a package call [download](https://github.com/kevva/download)

I uninstall it and remove it entirely from my app and my app works fine